# How fast must Jerry swim?

Tags: mathematics

The endless chasing scene between Tom and Jerry comes to a big, perfectly round lake. Jerry manages to escape Tom by a hair by plunging himself into the water. Tom can't swim - he can only run at a maximum speed of $v$ along the shoreline to try to catch Jerry. **How fast must Jerry swim in order to land safely?**

Comment: What does it mean to land safely? Where is safe, and how far away from Tom must Jerry be?

Comment: Assume both Tom and Jerry are "points" and safe means Tom is not at the exact same position where Jerry is landing. Of course a mathematical description would be more fun, and probably preferred by mathematicians (like myself, in fact)

Comment: @f" looks like one, but I am not sure if the accepted answer there is correct :/

Comment: @Pigpag A duplicate really applies to the question - if the answer on the duplicate is wrong, why not supply your own correct answer? (And explain why the existing answer is wrong in a comment on it)

Comment: @Milo I understand that. I wasn't aware of the other similar problem at the time of posting.

Answer (score 0):

Started solving based on the (probably erroneous) assumption that Jerry would swim in a straight continuous line.

From That

> Jerry needs to swim the chord length **2*R*sin(a/2)*** where a is the angle that contains the chord 
>  Tom needs to run the arc length **aR** 
>  Toms time will be **(a*R)/v** this will also be Jerry's target time 
>  So Jerry's speed needs to be 2<s>*R</s>*sin(a/2)*v/(a*<s>R</s>) 
>  This chart shows the relationship between angle and necessary speed so Jerry's best bet is to swim across the lake when he has to swim faster then v*2/pi  [image]

Comment: When Jerry swims to the center, he should at least try to swim in the opposite direction of where Tom is **at that time**. Therefore keep swimming in the same direction does not seem to be a good strategy :)